# How to use ng-include to switch views in angular?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have a `header.html` file. When a `div` inside it is clicked I want to switch to another view, let's say `main.html`. I used:

```
window.location("main.html");
```

How can I use `ng-include` to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For switching between views in angularJS one should use routing. You can use the [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). You should ideally not do that with an ng-include.